# Trying to wake up breaking points in gpu

Tags: debugging, cuda, nsight

I wan to debug with Nsight but the compiler do not stop in break points. I have enabled the option that generates debug information.

[image]

Here is the command line:

## Driver API (NVCC Compilation Type is .cubin, .gpu, or .ptx)

set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"     -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -o MP7.dir\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"

## Runtime API (NVCC Compilation Type is hybrid object or .c file)

set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"     -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Zi    " -o MP7.dir\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"

When the Nsight debuger starts the break point changes and an exclamation mark appear with the following box info:

```
The break point will not be currently be hit No CUDA device code for source file c:\users\..\file.cu. Did you enable device information in your project?
```

Both `.ilk` and `.pdb` files are in the same folder with the `.exe`. Also, in the Nsight debugger as `Working directory` that folder that includes the aforementioned files was set.

[image]

Moreover, breaking points were set inside the kernel functions.

How can I find out what is wrong?  I am in a deadlock.

Thank you!

**PS:** Win 7 64x, VS2010 64x solution, Nsight 3.2 64x, Cuda sdk 5.5 64x, Nsight is working fine in sdk samples, GeForce 9600 GT (**compute capability 1.1**)

Comment: Perhaps this discussion [Cuda-gdb not stopping at breakpoints inside kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723664/cuda-gdb-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-inside-kernel/21791042#21791042) could be of interest for you.

Comment: Thank you!. Also using `compute_20,sm_20` with cc. 1.1 corrupt my results. What should I do with that post? Is it considered as a duplicate? Should I erase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device is compute capability 1.1

But you are compiling for compute capability 2.0: "Code Generation   compute_20,sm_20"

Therefore there is no device code corresponding to your compute capability 1.1 device, and so you cannot properly set or hit breakpoints.

Change code generation to `compute_11,sm_11` to match your device.

Comment: I want to use atomicAdd in shared memory. Using the configuration,`compute_11,sm_11` returns `error : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors`. Shared memory `atomicAdds` are not working for `cc. 1.1`? I have to work in global memory?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the programming guide section on [atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions).  Atomic add in shared memory requires cc 1.2